# In r, use string just as if I had typed it in

Tags: r, string, types, stringr

I am dealing with one aspect of r that really confuses me. What I have built is a line of code invoking str_remove saved as a string. If I was to copy-paste that string into where I want to use this line of code, it works perfectly as intended.
However I cannot get r to interpret this code correctly. I have tried using e.g. parse, but the escape characters intended for str_remove regular expression throw up errors.

Is there not a simple way to just treat a string as if it was a line of typed code?

Here is my reproducible example:

Make toy data:

```
maf_list_context <- list(as.data.frame(cbind(c("ATTATCGAATT", "ATTATTTTAAA"), c("this one", "not that one"))),
                     as.data.frame(cbind(c("ATTACGTAATT", "ATTATTTTAAA"), c("this one too", "not that one either")))   )

maf_list_context <- lapply(maf_list_context, function(x)
{colnames(x) <- c("CONTEXT", "want_it")
return(x)
})
```

The idea is that context will be an argument to a function and that it can be flexible, so the user can supply any number of contexts of interest separated by commas. These will be stringr regular expressions designed to look for particular contexts in DNA within a string of 11 bases. Here for example we can use two contexts of interest. The code that follows combines these to make an expression for use later in selecting the appropriate rows from the dataframes in the list.

```
context <- "\\w{5}CG\\w{4}, \\w{4}CG\\w{5}"

contextvec <- unlist(str_split(context, pattern = ", "))

contextexpression <- c()

for(i in 1:length(contextvec)){
  
  contextexpression <- paste0(contextexpression, "str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '", contextvec[i], "') |")
  
}

contextexpression <- str_remove(contextexpression, pattern = " \\|$")
```

'contextexpression' is now:

```
[1] "str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{5}CG\\w{4}') |str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{4}CG\\w{5}')"
```

If I were to paste this expression directly into apply, it works precisely as I would want it.

```
 > lapply(maf_list_context, function(x){
+   
+   x[str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{5}CG\\w{4}') |str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{4}CG\\w{5}'), ]
+   
+ })

[[1]]
      CONTEXT  want_it
1 ATTATCGAATT this one

[[2]]
      CONTEXT      want_it
1 ATTACGTAATT this one too
```

But of course if I use the string there, it does not.

```
> lapply(maf_list_context, function(x){
+   
+   x[contextexpression, ]
+   
+ })

[[1]]
   CONTEXT want_it
NA    <NA>    <NA>

[[2]]
   CONTEXT want_it
NA    <NA>    <NA>
```

I have tried many different functions but none of them make this work. Is there are way of having r interpret this string as if I had typed it in directly?

The whole reprex:

```
if (!require("stringr") {
  install.packages("stringr", dependencies = TRUE)
  library("stringr")

maf_list_context <- list(as.data.frame(cbind(c("ATTATCGAATT", "ATTATTTTAAA"), c("this one", "not that one"))),
                         as.data.frame(cbind(c("ATTACGTAATT", "ATTATTTTAAA"), c("this one too", "not that one either")))   )

maf_list_context <- lapply(maf_list_context, function(x){
  colnames(x) <- c("CONTEXT", "want_it")
  return(x)
})

context <- "\\w{5}CG\\w{4}, \\w{4}CG\\w{5}"

contextvec <- unlist(str_split(context, pattern = ", "))

contextexpression <- c()

for(i in 1:length(contextvec)){
  
  contextexpression <- paste0(contextexpression, "str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '", contextvec[i], "') |")
  
}

contextexpression <- str_remove(contextexpression, pattern = " \\|$")

maf_list_select <- lapply(maf_list_context, function(x){
  
  x[contextexpression, ]
  
})
```

Comment: What you're after is `eval(parse(text=*))`. However 1) if the answer is eval+parse, you're probably asking the wrong question; 2) I think you may be a bit inexperienced with R to be considering stuff like this. Look for simpler ways of doing what you're doing

Comment: Hi Hong, I had already tried eval(parse(text = *)). However it throws up errors due to the regex expression, as I mentioned in the post.

 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'expr' in selecting a method for function 'eval': '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\w" 

As for simpler ways of doing what I'm doing, I would welcome suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely follow what you want your input to be and how to apply it, but your problem seems to be with what you're passing to the subset operator, i.e. `x[<codehere>]`

The subset operator expects a logical vector. When you "paste the expression" you are actually pasting an expression that gets evaluated to a logical vector, hence it properly subsets. When you pass the variable `contextexpression`, you are actually passing a string. As R sees it:

```
x[ "str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{5}CG\\w{4}') |str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{4}CG\\w{5}')", ]
```

Instead of (notice the syntax highlighting difference):

```
x[ str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{5}CG\\w{4}') |str_detect(x$CONTEXT, pattern = '\\w{4}CG\\w{5}'), ]
```

You want apply each context to each member of the list to get a logical vector and then subset.

```
purrr::map2(maf_list_context, contextvec, ~.x[str_detect(.x$CONTEXT, .y), ])
```

If you want to compare every item in `contextvec` to every item in `maf_list_context`, then it's a little more complicated but doable.

```
purrr::map2(
  maf_list_context, 
  purrr::map(
    maf_list_context, 
    function(data){
      purrr::reduce(contextvec, 
                    function(prev, cond) str_detect(data$CONTEXT, cond) | prev, 
                    .init = logical(length(contextvec))
      )
    } 
  ),
  ~.x[.y]
)
```

There's probably a more efficient way to short circuit the matching against the items in `maf_list_context`, but the general approach applies. The `str_detect` handles the comparison of a single condition against a single `maf_list` item. The `reduce` call combines the results of all the comparisons of `contextvec` to a single item in `maf_list_context` to a single boolean. The inner `map` iterates through `maf_list_context`. The outer `map2` iterates through the list of boolean values created by the inner `map` and `maf_list_context` to subset for matches.

If `maf_list_context` has n items and `contextvec` has m items:

- `reduce` makes m comparisons, resulting in 1 value
- `map` makes n calls to `reduce` result in n values
- `map2` makes n iterations to subset `maf_list_context`

Comment: Hi Marcus, many thanks for your answer. This seems to work perfectly on the reprex but isn't quite what I am after. What I want to do is search each element in maf_list_context for any of the contexts in contextvec. It seems map2() here applies the 1st element in .x to the first element in .y, the second in .x to the second in .y and so on. So here if we switch around the contexts from the lists in the toy data, or the order of the contexts supplied in 'context', now map2 returns an empty list.

Comment: To check my understanding -  if you have n items in `maf_list_context` and m items in `contextvec`, you are wanting to ultimately do n*m comparisons. I'll edit my answer to expand the solution for this cases.